# Firemonkey (Delphi XE5) Android Altitude from GPS

Tags: delphi, gps, firemonkey, delphi-xe5

Trying to get GPS altitude on an Android device using Delphi XE5/Firemonkey.

```
...
var
  AltDbl  : double;
...

  with Sender as TCustomLocationSensor do
    begin
    //did this to bypass any possible problem with the ToString conversion
    AltDbl := Altitude;
    lbAltitude.Text := FormatFloat( '###0.0## Meters', AltDbl );

    lbLatitude.Text := Latitude.ToString();
    lbLongitude.Text := Longitude.ToString();
    end;
```

The lat and lon do work but altitude returns "NAN".

Comment: You already started a discussion on this topic in the Embarcadero forum and people were helping you there. Why post this to SO as well?

Comment: Problem was not solved at EMB.  Not possible there's more expertise here?

Comment: That discussion is still ongoing, though...

Comment: If it is causing a problem for you I'll happily remove the question from here. I didn't start it at EMB so I can't remove it from there.  I was hoping someone has already done this and we could bypass the debugging but I guess not.

Comment: It is your choice. It does not make sense to carry on the same discussion on multiple sites at the same time, that's all.